# jspm/systemJs bundle, exclude external dependancies

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

I have a grunt task building my bundles for my app through systemJs/Jspm. I have 2 things I need bundled, the entire app, then the app.jsx itself. So I have 2 grunt tasks using `grunt-run`, the problem is, for one of the tasks I would like it *not* to bundle external dependancies. So here is the grunt-run task :

```
  app_jspm_bundle: {
        cmd: 'jspm',
        args: [
            'bundle',
            'build/client/app.js',
            'build/client/app.js'
        ]
    },
    jspm_bundle: {
        cmd: 'jspm',
        args: [
            'bundle',
            'build/client/irc/index.js',
            'build/client/bundle/irc.js'
        ]
    }
```

So jspm_bundle works great, however I would like the app_jspm_bundle task to not include external dependancies.

Based on the systemJs documentation, I tried adding this to the systemjs.congif.js file :

```
 meta: {
  "build/client/app.js": {
    "build": false
  }
},
```

However, this just generates my app.js file empty in my build folder. Is there any way to do bundle the app.js alone? Thanks!